# In ruby how do you rearrange an array of objects with id keys, give a new order of the array as an array?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I have an object with an array that looks like this:

```
some_object = {
  some_array: [
    { id: "foo0" },
    { id: "foo1" },
    { id: "foo2" },
    { id: "foo3" },
  ]
}
```

And I have an input of another array that I want to rearrange the array in

```
target_order = [
  { id: "foo0", new_position: 3 },
  { id: "foo3", new_position: 0 },
  { id: "foo1", new_position: 2 },
  { id: "foo2", new_position: 1 }
]
```

How do I go about using the second `target_order` array to modify the order of the first `some_object[:some_array]`?

Comment: Why do you have two `new_position: 3`? How do you determine whether `foo2` or `foo3` goes first?

Comment: Call `some_object[:some_array].sort_by! { ... }` and within the block, return the `new_position` value for the corresponding item from the `target_order` array.

Comment: Will target order always contain the same number of elements with the same keys id as `some_object[:some_array]`? If so then `some_object[:some_array] = target_order.each_with_object([]) { |h, arr| 
  arr[h[:new_position]] = h.slice(:id)
}` seems fairly simple

Comment: @engineersmnky, after posting an answer I noticed it is the same as the solution contained in your comment, so I deleted my answer and am directing you to post yours. I must remember `Hash#slice`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I take direction from no man :) and care little for the reputation of answering an ambiguous question with a presumptive answer; however I certainly appreciate your virtuous gesture and welcome you to reinstate your answer as you see fit

Comment: @engineersmnky, aye, aye, sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use `sort_by` with a custom block that finds the position of the item in the new array.

```rb
new_array = some_object[:some_array].sort_by do |item|
  order = target_order.detect { |order| order[:id] == item[:id] }
  next unless order

  order[:new_position]
end
```

This returns the following value.

```
=> [{:id=>"foo2"}, {:id=>"foo1"}, {:id=>"foo0"}, {:id=>"foo3"}]
```

---

## Further considerations

Perhaps you wanted to give each item a position in a list instead of just sorting them. For instance

```rb
target_order = [
  { id: "foo0", new_position: 0 },
  { id: "foo1", new_position: 2 }
]
```

would give

```
=> [{ id: "foo0" }, nil, { id: "foo1" }]
```

To do this, you should use `each_with_object` instead of `sort_by`.

```rb
new_array = target_order.each_with_object([]) do |order, memo|
  item = some_object[:some_array].detect { |item| item[:id] == order[:id] }
  next unless item

  memo[order[:new_position]] = item
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be simplistic, this is what I would do ...

```
temp_arr = []

target_order.each do |o|
  x = some_json_object[:some_array].find { |i| o[:id] == i[:id] }
  temp_arr[o[:new_position] - 1] = x
end

some_json_object = {
  "some_array": temp_arr
}
```

Comment: Please note that this assumes that the new_position order is not zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

If there is one to one correspondence between `some_array` and `target_order` elements, maybe you can do a direct assignment, something like:

```
some_object[:some_array] = target_order.sort_by{ |h| h[:new_position] }.map { |h| h.delete_if { |k, _| k == :new_position } }
```

So, you'll end up with

```
some_object #=> {:some_array=>[{:id=>"foo3"}, {:id=>"foo2"}, {:id=>"foo1"}, {:id=>"foo0"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sort, which has time-complexity of O(n*log(n)). Here is a O(n) solution.

```
{ some_array: target_order.each_with_object([]) { |h,a|
    a[h[:new_position]] = h.slice(:id) } }
  #=> {:some_array=>[{:id=>"foo3"}, {:id=>"foo2"}, {:id=>"foo1"}, {:id=>"foo0"}]}
```

Note that there is no reference to `some_object`.

If `some_object` is to be modified in place:

```
some_object[:some_array] = target_order.each_with_object([]) { |h,a|
  a[h[:new_position]] = h.slice(:id) }
some_object
  #=> {:some_array=>[{:id=>"foo3"}, {:id=>"foo2"}, {:id=>"foo1"}, {:id=>"foo0"}]}
```

Using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), though less efficient, one could write:

```
{ some_array: target_order.sort_by { |h| h[:new_position] }.map { |h| h.slice(:id) } }
  #=> {:some_array=>[{:id=>"foo3"}, {:id=>"foo2"}, {:id=>"foo1"}, {:id=>"foo0"}]}
```

Comment: See @engineersmnky's comment on the question.